# SFML textEntered not working properly

Tags: c++, sfml

so today I started looking into SFML and I found it quite interesting so decided to learn how to play with it, but I am already hitting some problems, I am trying to use textEntered event, but it is not working properly, it shows complete nonsense and text writes itself even without me pressing any key. [Heres link](http://postimg.org/image/us9fstc8h/)

Code

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(400, 400), "SFML works!");

    std::string display;

    sf::Font font;
    font.loadFromFile("arial.ttf");
    sf::Text text;
    text.setFont(font);
    text.setCharacterSize(30);
    text.setStyle(sf::Text::Bold);
    text.setColor(sf::Color::Red);
    text.setPosition(50, 50);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event Revent;

        while (window.pollEvent(Revent))
        {
            if (sf::Event::TextEntered)
            {
                std::cout << static_cast<char>(Revent.text.unicode);

                //text.setString(display);
            }
        }

        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Escape))
        {
            window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        //window.draw(text);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote `if (sf::Event::TextEntered)`, which evaluates to `true` (since it's not equal to 0).

You probably meant 
`if (Revent.type == sf::Event::TextEntered)`.

Using `Revent.text` is undefined behavior in this case (when you're not sure what type of event `Revent` contains) because `sf::Event` is an union, so only one of its members is usable at a time. You can read more about SFML events [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/window-events.php).

Comment: God damn it, it was so stupid, I was editing switch code from earlier and totally forgot. Thanks dude :)